# Apply function on every row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, apply

How can I apply the function `point_rotation` function on `Coordinates1`, `Coordinates2` columns in the below dataframe:

```
def point_rotation(point):
    """
    Changing axis
    """
    xcor, ycor = (700, 0)
    xcor1, ycor1 = (0, 0)
    xpoint, ypoint = point

    xnew = xpoint - xcor
    ynew = ypoint - ycor    
    xnew = xcor1 + math.cos(math.radians(270)) * (xnew - xcor1) - math.sin(math.radians(90)) * (ynew - ycor1)
    ynew = ycor1 + math.sin(math.radians(270)) * (xnew - xcor1) + math.cos(math.radians(90)) * (ynew - ycor1)
    return round(xnew, 0), round(ynew, 0)
```

Here's my current dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X_1': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
                   'Y_1': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86],
                   'X_2': [-3.58, -1.8, -3.5, 4.0, 1.48],
                   'Y_2': [-5.66, -4.1, -7.6, -7.8, -6.86]})

df['Coordinates1'] = list(zip(df.X_1, df.Y_1))
df['Coordinates2'] = list(zip(df.X_2, df.Y_2))
```

Output wanted: should have columns `Coordinates3` and `Coordinates4` which are basically derived from the `point_rotation` function by passing columns `Coordinates1` and `Coordinates2`.

I tried using the `apply` function, but it throws me an error: `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: hi. What is `height_units`. A defintion seems to be missing.

Comment: My bad. Updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use list comprehension. Your new point will be a tuple (similar to how you have defined `Coordinates1` and `Coordinates2`)

```
df['Coordinates3'] = [point_rotation(point) for point in df['Coordinates1']]
```

`apply` also seems to work :)

```
df['Coordinates4'] = df['Coordinates2'].apply(point_rotation)
```

Comment: Thanks this works! my dataframe columns were formatted as strings due to which it wasn't working initially.

Comment: @KaushikN if that helped you, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it, just click on the grey tick mark on the left of the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
df['Coordinates3'] = df['Coordinates1'].apply(point_rotation)
df['Coordinates4'] = df['Coordinates2'].apply(point_rotation)
```